# How to programmatically login a user in Symfony with its login and password?

Tags: symfony, symfony-security

I want to write a functional test like this:

```php
$user = $auth->login($username, $password);
```

Then I can check behaviors like:

- the login fails if the username/password doesn't match a user
- the login fails if the user is disabled
- the login works otherwise

**I don't want to go through HTTP requests for this**.

How can I do?

All examples I see either involve simulating an HTTP request or manually logging in a user without its password.

Edit: I use [Guard](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html).

Comment: Could you perhaps clarify what you are trying to accomplish?  The password and disabled stuff is easy enough.  But what do you mean by "the login works otherwise"?  Will you, for example, be kicking off additional code that relies on user roles being set?

Comment: @Cerad I want to test that my extensions to the security stuff in Symfony work properly (i.e. that the login feature works properly). "The password and disabled stuff is easy enough." -> If I can test that I'm interested to know how it is done "easily" for a starter?

Comment: All I can suggest would be to look at the tests in the SecurityBundle for examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UsernamePasswordToken` and Symfony authentication manager to do it, as explained in the docs, especially the first example: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html

Comment: Thank you that seems to be on track. However I get `No Authentication Provider found for token of class "...\UsernamePasswordToken"` (shortened for the comment). I think this is because I use Guard and Guard doesn't use these tokens. Any idea?

Comment: No, sorry. I haven't used Guard yet, so I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;

// main - your main firewall key    
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());
$tokenStorage->setToken($token);
```

Comment: How exactly would code fail if the password was incorrect?

Comment: Here we pass $user object. So we don't need a password.

Comment: From the question: "the login fails if the username/password doesn't match a user"

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am looking for a solution where I pass the login and password.